# Code Analysis Errors not appearing in Error List in VS2015 Update1

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-analysis

So, just updated Visual Studio 2015 to Update 1 (Windows 8.1).

On a large project we've been working on for a while, running Code Analysis on the whole solution (or individual projects) runs CA properly, tells me the build failed, but then doesn't list the errors in the Error List.

In the build Output window, though, I can see the list of errors, but as it's the Output window, I can't do anything with them (e.g., right-click and suppress).

We've got another Windows 8.1 box here that is experiencing exactly the same issue, but then a couple of others that don't (same project, same expected CA errors).

Is this something that's been broken in Update 1, or am I missing something?

Oh, and restarting Studio doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Right, turns out I was being daft.

In the Error List, you can toggle Errors and Warnings on and off.  Seems code analysis errors get listed as Warnings now.  Guess who'd turned off warnings from that list?

[image: Error list with Warnings turned on]

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to know. I was puzzled when VS2015 started listing things as "warnings" when I know that fxcopcmd.exe lists them as errors.